# prolog matrix treating column

Tags: matrix, prolog, row, sublist

I'm working with matrix where each sublist is a row:

```
Matrix =[[-,-,-,-,a,-],
         [-,-,-,-,b,-],
         [-,-,-,-,a,-],
         [-,-,-,-,d,a],
         [-,-,-,-,a,a],
         [-,-,a,a,a,a],
         [-,-,-,-,d,a]].
```

My goal is to find if there are four consecutive positions in a sublist with the same character that sent.

```
veryRow(_,[]).
veryRow(X,[T|TS]) :- row(X,T), veryRow(X,TS).
row(X,[A,B,C,D|_]) :- A \= X; B \= X; C \= X; D \= X.
row(X,[_|Xs]):- row(X,Xs).
```

Must return true when a sublist four consecutive elements.

my imputs is :

```
veryRow(a,[[-,-,-,-,a,-],
         [-,-,-,-,b,-],
         [-,-,-,-,a,-],
         [-,-,-,-,d,a],
         [-,-,-,-,a,a],
         [-,-,a,a,a,a],
         [-,-,-,-,d,a]]).
```

Because not found?

Thanks

Comment: `veryRow` will fail as soon as it finds a row that doesn't succeed for `row`.

Comment: but with the cut " ! " . Does not stop the execution if  Row is true ?

Comment: It never gets that far. The cut only prevents backtracking for more solutoins *if* the call to `row` succeeds. For the very first row in the second argument, `veryRow(X, [T|TS])` fails because `T` doesn't have 4 consecutive `X`s. And `veryRow(_, [])` fails because the second argument isn't the empty list. So the predicate fails completely. Your logic for `veryRow` requires that `row` is successful.

Comment: ahh okey!! understand  thanks @lurker

Comment: but now: 
    `veryRow(_,[]).`
    `veryRow(X,[T|TS]) :- \+ row(X,T), veryRow(X,TS).`
    `row(X,[X,X,X,X|_]).`
    `row(X,[_|Xs]):- row(X,Xs).`
Yes always Row return False, veryRow continue see other list. But is possible that solution this in half Matrix. 
As I can do that predicate , to finish correctly? I don't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the top, I think that `veryRow` needs to be rethought. The name is not satisfactory because it doesn't describe what the rule does very well. But I shall leave it as is and leave it to you to choose a more suitable name (perhaps `four_in_a_row` or something like that).

The base case, `veryRow(_, []).` is problematic. It succeeds for any element as the first argument and the empty list as the second, yet those arguments don't logically meet the requirement that this rule is supposed to decide on (that the first argument occurs 4 times consecutively as an element in the second argument). So let's throw that rule out.

Your second rule is also problematic:

```
veryRow(X,[T|TS]) :- row(X,T),!, veryRow(X,TS).
```

This rule says that *`X` is consecutive in `[T|TS]` **if** `X` is consecutive in `T` **and** `X` is consecutive in `TS`*. This is obviously incorrect since you want it to succeed if `X` is consecutive in *at least one* of the rows in `[T|TS]`, not *all* the rows. The cut you inserted doesn't change this meaning.

Certainly the following would be true as a simple base case, which is the element occurs consecutively in the head of the list:

```
veryRow(X, [T|_]) :- row(X, T).
```

Note this is all you need for the base case. It succeeds as soon as `row(X, T)` succeeds and no further calls should be made. But what if it fails (`X` is not consecutive in `T`)? Then you need your other clause to handle the rest of the list:

```
veryRow(X, [_|Ts]) :- veryRow(X, Ts).
```

This simply says, *`X` is consecutive in `[_|Ts]` if `X` is consecutive in `Ts`*.

This will ultimately fail if `Ts` is `[]` which is fine since it wouldn't be true.

You should get rid of your cuts, and this rule will work and succeed for each case that it finds four consecutive elements. If there are multiple such cases, you'll get multiple successes/solutions. If you only want it to succeed once, you can use `once/1`:

```
onceVeryRow(X, L) :- once(veryRow(X, L)).
```

---

Your first implementation of `row/2` was fine before you changed it (and with the cut removed):

```
row(X, [X, X, X, X|_]).
row(X, [_|T]) :-
    row(X, T).
```

Comment: thank you very much!! really. It is working properly and most importantly understand. Thank you